# Class loader error - unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am quite new to Spring and Java as a whole and I am currently working on an API. I've got this code which accesses MSSQL database, retrieves the results and IS SUPPOSED TO visualize it, but it doesn't work. I mean, if I would only call the procedure and visualize the result set, it would work normally. The problem is that I can't work with the "RatingProcedure" object. When I try get some object's value, it shows me following **error**:

> Hibernate: 
>       {call dis_entity.spdcmpracovnici(?,?,?,?)}
>   2019-09-02 01:56:01.355  WARN 8720 --- [nio-8050-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class com.pproi.dcm.ratingprocedure.RatingProcedure ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; >com.pproi.dcm.ratingprocedure.RatingProcedure is in unnamed module of loader >org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @7193df92)]

**The code:**

```
@GetMapping("/replacements/{sourceId}/workers")
    public ResponseEntity<List<PossibleReplacementResponseModel>> getReplacements(@PathVariable Integer sourceId,
            @RequestParam(required = false) Integer targetWorkerId,
            @RequestParam(required = false) Integer targetLineId,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String targetWorkplaces) {

        List<PossibleReplacementResponseModel> response = new ArrayList<>();

        // 400 Bad Request
        if ((targetLineId != null && targetWorkerId != null) || (targetWorkplaces != null && targetLineId == null))
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();

        StoredProcedureQuery ratingProcedure = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("dcmrating");

        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = ratingProcedure.setParameter("pk_target_worker", targetWorkerId)
                .setParameter("pk_target_sdl", targetLineId).setParameter("pk_target_workplaces", targetWorkplaces)
                .setParameter("pk_source_sdl", sourceId);

        List<RatingProcedure> ratings = storedProcedure.getResultList();

        for(RatingProcedure rating : ratings) {
            PossibleReplacementResponseModel responseModel = new PossibleReplacementResponseModel();
            Optional<Worker> _worker = workerRepository.findById(rating.getPersonalId());

            if(_worker.isPresent()) {
                Worker worker = _worker.get();
                responseModel.setId(worker.getId());
                responseModel.setName(worker.getFullName());
                responseModel.setSkills(findWorkersSkills(worker));
                responseModel.setPhysicalExamination(findWorkersMedicalExaminationEndDate(worker));
                responseModel.setExams(findWorkersExams(worker));
                responseModel.setRestrictions(findWorkersRestrictions(worker));
                responseModel.setRating(rating.getRating());
            }
            response.add(responseModel);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
```

I probably even have an idea about the solution! I probably should customize my Restart Classloader as seen in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload), but there my skills end and I have no idea what I should specify in the file.

Any ideas?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 27):

A simple workaround is to [disable the Restart](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-restart-disable) by setting the system property:

```
spring.devtools.restart.enabled = false
```

For example, when using spring-boot maven plugin, launch the app this way:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.devtools.restart.enabled=false"
```

Comment: I spent 8 hours pulling my hair, till I saw this answer. After I fixed the removed the dev tools jar the issue went away.

Comment: @RahulKhimasia Glad to contribute to saving your hair ;-)

Comment: in deed this is just a workaround and not a solution. you are disabling the automatic restart and so then you have to restart manually after each change. Like "my car has a little malfunction, so I don't use my care anymore.".

Comment: I recommend that you verify if the same class loader is used. For instance for Hibernate you might use a Cache Provider like EhCache which is using a different ClassLoader  then the devtools are using `RestartClassLoader`. So make sure that both are using the same when you initialize the EhCache. See above an example in my answer.

Answer (score 16):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class <Class_Name> cannot be cast to class <Class_Name> (<Class_Name> is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader <Class_Name> is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

This is related to spring dev tools package. Try removing the package if it is not required.

Comment: and what if spring dev tools is required?

Comment: Not really an answer. Your answer is like "Don't use Spring. You won't have problems".

Answer (score 5):

Maybe what is happening here is that:
Reference is being created of the base class and then casting is happening for the inherited class.

Let me give an example. Assume that we have a base class named "BaseClass" and one class "ChildClass" is extending "BaseClass".

```
BaseClass bClass = new BaseClass(); // NOTICE HERE -> new BaseClass();


// Somewhere in next code lines
ChildClass childClass = (ChildClass) bClass;
```

This will **throw the error** which you are mentioning.

**DO this:**

```
BaseClass bClass = new ChildClass(); // NOTICE HERE -> new ChildClass();


// Somewhere in next code lines
ChildClass childClass = (ChildClass) bClass;
```

I hope this will solve the problem as it solved mine

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you are using the devtools the ClassLoader get set to a different one `org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader` then the Cache Provider / Framework you are using.

In case you are using JCache or EhCache you simple initialize the Cache Manager by making sure that you are using the same class loader.

More information and background can be found [here](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000041647471/en)

```
import javax.cache.CacheManager;
import javax.cache.Caching;
import javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@Slf4j
public class CachingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CacheManager myCacheManager() {
     
    // The trick is to use "Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()"
    // which overwrites the default class loader set internally by the cache provider
    // with this you ensure both Class loaders are the same when you are using the devtools 

        CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager(provider.getDefaultURI(), Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        return cacheManager;
    }


    // Optional - in the same class or separate class you can verify the 
    // reload which gets initiated by the devtools. So you can check if the 
    // Class loader of your cache Manager and the one currently used by the
    // Spring Framework is the same
    
    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    CacheManager cacheManager;

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefreshEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent ctxEvt) {           
        ClassLoader loader1 = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        ClassLoader loader2 = cacheManager.getClassLoader();
        log.debug("{} = {}", loader1, loader2);
    }
}
```

The expected output should then be

```
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@3478e262 = org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@3478e262
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when I am connecting to the mysql db via persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="2.2">
    <!-- the name="pu" will be used in MainApplicationClass -->
    <persistence-unit name="pu1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_hibernate_jpa_db?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="hilal" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="hilal" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

the only solution for me is to start mvn with the command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="Dspring.devtools.restart.enabled=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it's working in my case :

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

Answer (score -3):

This might work : If you are using springboot devtools in your project (pom/gradle), then make sure your class that is using @SpringBootApplication is  ***"public"***.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
  public static void main(String ... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class,args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

removing the dependency of devtools from pom.xml will help

```
<!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
-->
```

Comment: arguably, also removing spring boot entirely, or stopping trying to run the application will solve the problem with the same logic

Answer (score -4):

You should be main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");

    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).