# How to fix faktor ips ClassloaderRuntimeRepository not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: hibernate, faktor-ips

I am trying to persist a class `Angebot` which has an Attribute `KfzVertrag`, which is a policy class generated by faktor ips. I am using Spring Boot.

`Angebot` looks like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Angebot {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    private String angebotName;
    private String produktName;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private KfzVertrag vertrag;

    public Angebot() {
    }

    //...Getters and Setters...
```

`KfzVertrag` looks like this:

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("KV")
@IpsPolicyCmptType(name = "kfz.KfzVertrag")
@IpsAssociations({ "KfzHaftpflichtdeckung", "KfzAssistancedeckung" })
@IpsConfiguredBy(KfzProdukt.class)
@IpsDocumented(bundleName = "org.faktorips.beispiel.model.model-label-and-descriptions", defaultLocale = "de")
public class KfzVertrag extends Vertrag {

    //...


    /**
     * Membervariable fuer die Beziehung KfzHaftpflichtdeckung.
     * 
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @generated
     */
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "kfzVertrag", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = KfzHaftpflichtdeckung.class, orphanRemoval = true)
    private KfzHaftpflichtdeckung kfzHaftpflichtdeckung = null;

    /**
     * Membervariable fuer die Beziehung KfzAssistancedeckung.
     * 
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @generated
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "kfzVertrag", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = KfzAssistancedeckung.class, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<KfzAssistancedeckung> kfzAssistancedeckungen = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Erzeugt eine neue Instanz von KfzVertrag.
     * 
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @generated
     */
    @IpsGenerated
    public KfzVertrag() {
        super();
    }

    //... (The class is very large)
```

I have a regular Spring repository exteding `JpaRepository<Angebot, Long>`. When I want to save an instance of `Angebot` into my h2 database I always get this error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not serialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not serialize
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.likki.fips.kfzlinkki.model.Service.save(Service.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.likki.fips.kfzlinkki.page.DetailPage.saveAngebot(DetailPage.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.likki.fips.kfzlinkki.pmo.AngebotDetailsPmo.save(AngebotDetailsPmo.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.InvokeMethod.invoke(InvokeMethod.java:61) ~[linkki-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.PropertyAccessor.invoke(PropertyAccessor.java:75) ~[linkki-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.invoke(ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.java:154) ~[linkki-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.push(ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.java:127) ~[linkki-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.push(AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.java:70) ~[linkki-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.push(AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.java:70) ~[linkki-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.ui.aspects.ButtonInvokeAspectDefinition.lambda$initModelUpdate$3d35fc86$1(ButtonInvokeAspectDefinition.java:47) ~[linkki-core-vaadin23-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:206) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:448) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:265) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:447) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:447) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:62) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:71) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:438) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:419) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:419) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:320) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:115) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1567) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:299) ~[flow-server-23.0.3.jar:23.0.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:109) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.3.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not serialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.serialize(SerializationHelper.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.serialize(SerializationHelper.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.clone(SerializationHelper.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor$SerializableMutabilityPlan.deepCopyNotNull(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor$SerializableMutabilityPlan.deepCopyNotNull(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.MutableMutabilityPlan.deepCopy(MutableMutabilityPlan.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.deepCopy(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:308) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.deepCopy(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:304) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.deepCopy(TypeHelper.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:279) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:427) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:637) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:652) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.faktorips.runtime.ClassloaderRuntimeRepository
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349) ~[na:na]
    at org.faktorips.runtime.internal.ProductConfiguration.writeObject(ProductConfiguration.java:167) ~[faktorips-runtime-21.12.4.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1145) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.serialize(SerializationHelper.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    ... 145 common frames omitted
```

For reasons described in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72365542/faktor-ips-classcastexception-when-casting-iproductcomponent-to-concrete-product), I have disabled the `spring.devtools.restart` classloader. But I'm not sure if that is the cause of this issue.

I have done another project where the persistence works whithout any problems. But I the only way in which this project differs from the other is that I had to disable the `spring.devtools.restart` in this one, and I have built in a Linkki UI version 1.5.0 on the other one, and on this one I am trying to work with Linkki version 2.0.0. But I don't see how that would effect the persistence.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not a problem with linkki. It seems that Hibernate is trying to persist the ProductConfiguration through serialization. To serialize the ProductConfiguration, you would need to configure an IRuntimeRepositoryLookup in your RuntimeRepository. However, this doesn't matter because serializing an object is not the right way to use Faktor-IPS with JPA.

You need to configure a JPA `AttributeConverter<ProductConfiguration, String>` annotated with `@Converter(autoApply = true)`. Maybe your JPA version is different from your previous project, so it needs to be configured differently?

Comment: Using the `IRuntimeRepositoryLookup` (or something similar) is also necessary to implement the `AttributeConverter` - you need to be able to convert the `ProductConfiguration` to a String for the database, for example using `productConfiguration.getProductComponent().getId()` and then finding that product component again when reading, for which you need an `IRuntimeRepository` - preferably that is always the same repository while your application is running and you use the lookup to find that instance.